# How can I check whether the values in a column all belong to an array?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

The following tables are present:

```
+----------------------+
| Tables_in_automobile |
+----------------------+
| car has options      |
| car sold             |
| company              |
| customer             |
| members              |
| model                |
| model has options    |
| options              |
+----------------------+

MariaDB [automobile]> describe model;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| company name    | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| model name      | varchar(100) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| number of seats | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cost            | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

MariaDB [automobile]> describe options;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| option name | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cost        | int(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

MariaDB [automobile]> describe `model has options`;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| company name | varchar(100) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| model name   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| option id    | int(10)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I need to find the particular car models which satisfy the following:

1. Number of seats >= a certain value
2. The car comes with a set of options

The following query satisfies the first condition, but if any car has any **one or more** of the ***set of options provided via a query***, it is included in the result. I need only those cars which have the exact options which were provided:

```
SELECT `company name`, `model name`, `number of seats`, 
    SUM(`options`.`cost`)+`model`.`cost` AS 'cost' 
FROM `model` NATURAL JOIN `model has options` JOIN `options` 
WHERE `model has options`.`option id` = `options`.`id` 
    AND `number of seats`>=3 
    AND `option id` IN (3,4,7) 
GROUP BY `company name`, `model name` 
ORDER BY `cost`
```

Comment: Having count [distinct] ... = 3

Answer (score 1):

A HAVING clause can be used to ensure that the number of distinct matched options is equal to the number of options supplied.

```
SELECT `company name`, `model name`, `number of seats`, 
    SUM(`options`.`cost`)+`model`.`cost` AS 'cost' 
FROM `model` NATURAL JOIN `model has options` JOIN `options` 
WHERE `model has options`.`option id` = `options`.`id` 
    AND `number of seats`>=3 
    AND `option id` IN (3,4,7) 
GROUP BY `company name`, `model name` 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT (`option id`)) = 3
ORDER BY `cost`
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps.

But I need it to be more precise.
Is there any way to check whether the options are exactly the ones that are specified in the array?

Comment: [screenshot of the webpage](https://photos.app.goo.gl/ZylHwIJMAftDQtjw2)

Comment: The combination of the IN and the COUNT(DISTINCT) will ensure this - there's no way to have three distinct options that aren't 3,4, and 7 in this query.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Thanks a lot!

I worked around it in the php.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
SELECT Field FROM model
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(Field, "company name,model name,number of seats") = 0;
```

Something like that will find any `Field` values that are not in that array.  Returning the empty set indicates that all are found.  So another approach is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...`

Limitation:  Since commas are used as separators, no item in the array may have a comma.

Comment: I'll try this out. This should work accurately. Thanks!